# Getting Transform of Enum Objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am confused about how to get the `transform` component of `Enum` objects that are bones of a character.

This is easily done in Mecanim by using the `GetBoneTransform` method, so I am trying to write a function to do this when I am not using a `Mecanim` skeleton.

The following is my class:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GetTransform : MonoBehaviour
{   
    public enum BradBodyBones
    {
        JtPelvis = 0,
        JtSkullA = 1,
        JtSkullB = 2
    }

    void Start()
    {
        GetEnumTransform(JtPelvis);  // This is the error line.
    }

    Transform GetEnumTransform(BradBodyBones boneName)
    {
        Transform tmpTransf;
        GameObject enumObject = GameObject.Find(boneName.ToString());
        tmpTransf = enumObject.transform;
        return tmpTransf;
    }
}
```

I know this is wrong, because `JtPelvis` in the `Start()` is highlighted red, so can someone please help me understand how I can do this?

In other words, how can I implement a function similar to `GetBoneTransform` of Unity's `HumanBodyBones` enumeration that when I use it in my `Start()` for example, it gives me the `transform` of `JtPelvis`?

Basically, `GetEnumTransform(JtPelvis);` of my `Start()` should return the `transform` component of that bone...

Comment: You'll have to make your `GetTransform` specific to Mecanim, or make a 'strategy' that does this. Within this implementation you can reach their implementation by using mapping. So all theres left, is mapping `myBodyBones` to `HumanBodyBones` 'somehow'.

Comment: Can you post your transform class?

Comment: @ehh I added the class to my original post. Please let me know what I am doing wrong. In the function definition, `.boneName` and `.Transform` are highlighted red.

Comment: Do you have a chance to look at my answer below, I think it is a better solution than working with enums

Comment: @Caramiriel Thank you, but I do not want to map them onto mecanim bones; instead on a different skeleton. I just need to know how to get the transform of in individual bones via their index. Please see my `GetTransform` class. How do I define the `GetEnumTransform`  function to do this?

Comment: @ehh Hi, Yes, it is much better, but I am not trying to retrieve the transforms from anywhere; instead I am trying to work them out. In other words, getting Unity to calculate the transform component for me, similar to mecanim's `GetBoneTransform` function. Basically, I am trying to complete the `GetEnumTransform` function in my original post, to work out the transform of the parameter passed onto it. I know there is a `Transform` dot operator, but cannot seem to figure out how to use it in the function...

Comment: I am confuse, what are GameObject and Transform classes? Please post the implementation, it is hard to help like this.

Comment: @ehh I have updated my entire post. This is all the implementation. At the moment, the line in my `Start()` gives an error. I also tried `(BradBodyBones.boneName).ToString()` to no avail...

Comment: Did you try:
GameObject.Find(boneName.ToString()).GetComponentInChildren<BradBodyBones>();

Comment: Yes, I did. Many thanks. Not directly, but indirectly (by making me realize what I was doing wrong) it resolved my issue. I will post the answer shortly... Thanks for your help ehh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class GetTransform : MonoBehaviour
{

    public enum BradBodyBones
    {
        JtPelvis = 0,
        JtSkullA = 1,
        JtSkullB = 2
        // more here later ...
    }


    void Start()
    {
        // Debug.Log(BradBodyBones.JtSkullA);  // JtSkullA  which is a string!
        // Debug.Log((int)(BradBodyBones.JtSkullA));  // 1  which is an integer!

        // GameObject Pelvis = GameObject.Find("JtPelvis");
        // Debug.Log(Pelvis.transform.position.x);

        Debug.Log(GetEnumTransform(BradBodyBones.JtPelvis).position.x);
        Debug.Log(GetEnumTransform(BradBodyBones.JtPelvis).position.y);
        Debug.Log(GetEnumTransform(BradBodyBones.JtPelvis).position.z);
    }


    Transform GetEnumTransform(BradBodyBones boneName)
    {
        Transform tmpTransf;
        GameObject enumObject = GameObject.Find(boneName.ToString()); // GameObject.Find(boneName.ToString()).GetComponentInChildren<BradBodyBones>();
        tmpTransf = enumObject.transform;
        return tmpTransf;
    }
}
```

*Many thanks to ehh + Caramiriel + PearsonArtPhoto for helping me resolve this.*

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a [dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Using an enum also is safer, as you won't be affected by a small typo. You then have to make the appropriate transforms. For instance, your code could look like this:

```
public class GetTransform : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform headBone;
    public Transform pelvisBone;

    private Dictionary<myBonesBody,Transform> mEnumToBone;

    void Start() {
         mEnumToBone=new Dictionary<myBonesBody,Transform>();
         mEnumToBone.Add(myBodyBone.skull,headBone); //Continue as such.

         mEnumToBone[myBodyBone.skull];   //This is how you retrieve the value from the dictionary
    }

    public Transform GetTransform(myBonesBody part) {
        return mEnumToBone[part];
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to write a function that "gets" their transforms for me, similar to mecanim's `GetBoneTransform` for example something like `GetTransform(myPelvis)` but in your answer (dictionary/class) I cannot seem to find that...

Comment: Thanks. I should have explained clearly. I do not actually have the transforms. I am trying to get them. Not get them from a place where they exist (e.g. a dictionary) but actually work them out. I think your answer pre-supposes that I have stored the transforms somewhere. Please see my class and the function i am trying to define. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Enum is better to be use in case that your enum list does not have a potential to be changed during the application life cycle. I was using enum, for example, in case of odd/even, dice numbers (1 to 6), week (Sunday to Saturday) and so on.

In your case, I was changing the architecture.
Something like:

```
public class GetTransform : MonoBehaviour
{    
    Transform GetEnumTransform(BodyBones bodyBone)
    {            
        return bodyBone.GetBodyBoneTransform();
    }

}

class BodyBones
{
     protected Transform _transform;

     public BodyBones(Transform transform)
     {
         _transform = transform;
     }

     public Transform GetBodyBoneTransform()
     {
         return _transform;
     }
}

class JtPelvis : BodyBones
{
     public JtPelvis (Transform transform): base(transform)
}

class JtSkull : BodyBones
{
     public JtSkull (Transform transform): base(transform)
}
```